# How can we run cucumber tests via a batch file?

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, cucumber, browser-automation

I want to run my Cucumber Features using an executable batch file but am not sure how to do it.

My batch file must allow me to run test cases selectively also i.e bases on Tags or any particular feature file in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is a starting point for you:
In your terminal:

```
gedit myscript.sh
```

Write following in your script:

```
echo "starting script"
cd /yourproject/homefolder
mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @$1”
echo "ending script"
```

Save the script, then in terminal make it executable by typing

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Then call it like this

```
./myscript.sh Smoke
```

Command above runs all scenarios using tag Smoke.

This is all from my head, didn't test it, but it should work! 
Same procedure for myscript.bat
create myscript.bat and write in it following:

```
echo "starting script"
cd C://yourproject/homefolder
mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @$1”
echo "ending script"
```

Then call it like this

```
myscript.bat Smoke
```